# Partial invoicing in Magento 2 - how to update order line items with which items to invoice via csv?

Tags: magento2, invoice

Partial invoicing in Magento 2 - how to update order line items with which items to invoice via csv?

For example, let's say I have an order that has 4 items on it. 2 of those items are on back order. So, I want to invoice and ship the other 2 items.

How can I, via csv, invoice those 2 items and update only the tracking number for those 2 items?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To partially invoice specific items and update tracking information via CSV in Magento 2, export the order and add columns "qty_invoiced" or "qty_shipped" with the invoiced or shipped quantities and "tracking_number" with the tracking number for shipped items. Then import the updated CSV file, mapping the columns to the corresponding fields in Magento 2. The order line items will be updated with the new quantities and tracking information. Be sure to backup the order information before making any changes.